# How to always open the `:h` as a split from the current window?

Tags: vimrc, vim-windows

As title. Say I have A|B and already called `:h foo` on B then if I call `:h bar` on A it will not create a new split under A but change the content of the split from B instead. What I expect is that I can open a help page for each window under the current tabpage.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue, what I did was make an command abbreviation so that :h runs `:s h <arg>`. Like so:

```lua
cabbrev h split \| h
cabbrev help split \| help

-- Or in Neovim
vim.cmd.cabbrev 'h split | h'
```

Comment: or `:command -nargs=* Help split | help <args>`

Comment: But note that this still makes the second `:help` command re-use the current help window.